Examples of Cross-Dialectal Compatible Translation/Transliteration?
In his paper Research Frontiers in Sino-Islamic Linguistics, from 1976, Paul Wexler briefly explores the idea of translating and/or transliterating with the goal of cross-dialectal comprehension in the negative.
On page 58 of Journal of Chinese Linguistics, January 1976, Vol. 4, No. 1, he states:

There is no evidence that Muslim scribes ever attempted to select characters with an eye to cross-dialectal comprehension. In order to be able to select characters with a common reading for most dialects, the scribes would have had to be multidialectal.

Earlier, on page 57, he gives the following example:

For example, if the Arabic or Persian syllable su is written with the character 素, then a speaker of Mandarin will read it as sù, but for a Cantonese speaker, this character would be read as sou. Had the Cantonese speaker intended to select a symbol for Arabic su, he would probably have used 数 or 树 (pronounced as shǔ, shù respectively in Mandarin). The absence of a common transcriptional system for Arabic and Persian—or for that matter, for any foreign language written with Chinese characters—has important benefits for us，since we can more readily identify the dialect region of the scribes. For example, in an early 13th century text, 'Muhammad' is written in characters which would be read by a Cantonese as ma-ha-mat, which is most likely the dialect of the scribe since a Mandarin reading of the characters would be má-xiá-wù C-16 (Himly).30


It is an interesting concept and there are, surely, plenty of modern day examples that likewise prove "the dialect region of the scribes"; think: 福尔摩斯, 瑞士, etc.
Conversely, cross-dialectal translation/transliteration seems to be something rarely touched on. Yet, Wexler clearly had this concept when drafting his paper.
Do examples of translating or transliterating with the goal of cross-dialectal unity exist?
